# jBPM with eclipse error java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jbpm

I'm trying to create a process using jBPM, I'm using Jboss 7.1 server and I  installed jbpm plugin for eclipse Kepler and I added jars. Now I create a simple hello world project but I got allways an error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: RuntimeManagerFactory was not initialized, see previous errors
    at org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeManagerFactory$Factory.get(RuntimeManagerFact     ory.java:112)
 at org.jbpm.test.JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase.<init>   (JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase.java:119)
    at org.jbpm.test.JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase.<init>    (JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase.java:157)
    at com.sample.ProcessTest.<init>(ProcessTest.java:54)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Any help please ?

this is the main code :

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
 import org.jbpm.test.JBPMHelper;
import org.kie.api.KieBase;
 import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession; 
import org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeEngine;
import org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder;
import org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeManager;
import org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeManagerFactory;
import org.kie.api.task.TaskService;
import org.kie.api.task.model.TaskSummary;

public class ProcessMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
    KieBase kbase = kContainer.getKieBase("kbase");

    RuntimeManager manager = createRuntimeManager(kbase);
    RuntimeEngine engine = manager.getRuntimeEngine(null);
    KieSession ksession = engine.getKieSession();
    TaskService taskService = engine.getTaskService();

    ksession.startProcess("com.sample.bpmn.hello");

    // let john execute Task 1
    List<TaskSummary> list = taskService.getTasksAssignedAsPotentialOwner("john", "en-UK");
    TaskSummary task = list.get(0);
    System.out.println("John is executing task " + task.getName());
    taskService.start(task.getId(), "john");
    taskService.complete(task.getId(), "john", null);

    // let mary execute Task 2
    list = taskService.getTasksAssignedAsPotentialOwner("mary", "en-UK");
    task = list.get(0);
    System.out.println("Mary is executing task " + task.getName());
    taskService.start(task.getId(), "mary");
    taskService.complete(task.getId(), "mary", null);

    manager.disposeRuntimeEngine(engine);
    System.exit(0);
}

private static RuntimeManager createRuntimeManager(KieBase kbase) {
    JBPMHelper.startH2Server();
    JBPMHelper.setupDataSource();
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.jbpm.persistence.jpa");
    RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder builder = RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.Factory.get()
        .newDefaultBuilder().entityManagerFactory(emf)
        .knowledgeBase(kbase);
    return RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get()
        .newSingletonRuntimeManager(builder.get(), "com.sample:example:1.0");
}

  }
```

Comment: Can you show how you're get `RuntimeManager` or the complete example that generates the error?

Comment: I update my question and I show the main code

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and i solved it!

If you get an eye on the RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder  [source code](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=droolsjbpm-knowledge-master/kie-api/src/main/java/org/kie/api/runtime/manager/RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.java) , you will notice that the method **Factory.get()** throws the error you are getting if an instance of **RuntimeEnvironmentBuilderFactory** is null!

But how does it construct that instance?
It uses this class **org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder**
So because you do not have have this class in you classpath, the instance can't be constructed and remains null.

You can find this class in jbpm-runtime-manager-6.4.0.Final.jar or in any other jar of your choice.

Hope this helps!